# Getting username after authentification with coredata predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am a beginner in Xcode. I would like to get the `username` or the `ID` after the user enters their login and password in textfield. I am sure I am doing wrong.
My code bug is after the access granted.

app due to uncaught exception

```
 '`NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: 
                                                      object cannot be nil`'
```

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)stepInButton:(id)sender {

AppDelegate *appDelegateCoreData = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegateCoreData managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
            @"(playerlogin = %@) AND (playerpassword =%@)", self.loginTextField.text, self.passwordTextField.text];

[request setPredicate:pred];
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) {
    self.loginStatusLabel.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"LOGIN IN ACCESS DENIED");

} else {
    NSLog(@"LOGIN IN ACCESS GRANTED");


    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"playerfirstname"];
    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:keyPathExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if ([objects count] == 0) {

        // Handle the error.

    }

    else {

        if ([objects count] > 0) {

            NSString *playerFirstName = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"playerfirstname"];
            NSLog(@"PlayerFirstName: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"playerfirstname"]);
            self.welcomePlayerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Welcome %@", playerFirstName];
        }

    }



    self.loginStatusLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.signButton.hidden = YES;
    self.stepButton.hidden =YES;
    self.loginStatusLabel.text =(@"Access Granted");
    self.loginStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.loginStatusLabel.hidden = NO;

    //FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"] animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: is `playerfirstname` (should rename as `playerFirstName`) an `NSDateAttributeType` (not `NSStringAttributeType`) ? also you could simply specify the name in properties to fetch, and in order for the request to work as you expect you should change the result type to dictionary. and why not simply get the first name from the objects returned in the first query?

Comment: I don't see anything which is trying to insert an object into an NSMutableArray, either explicitly or implicitly. So, perhaps the crash is in a different part of the code than what you've shared. Can you set an exception breakpoint (Debug >> Breakpoints >> Create Exception Breakpoint) and find exactly which line is crashing and share it with us?

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I tryed with NSStringAttributeType but that dont work. i want to get the firstname directly from the objet like you said. But i dont know how. i know objects array contain 1 record with all the player info. Can you please help me ? Thanks   For Ryan, i think its this line --> [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]]; Thanks you too .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I got it.

I retieved the playerFirstName directly form object like Dan Shelly said. Thanks you Dan.

```
- (IBAction)stepInButton:(id)sender {

AppDelegate *appDelegateCoreData = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegateCoreData managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player"      inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"(playerlogin = %@) AND (playerpassword =%@)", self.loginTextField.text, self.passwordTextField.text];

[request setPredicate:pred];
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) {
self.loginStatusLabel.hidden = NO;
NSLog(@"LOGIN IN ACCESS DENIED");

} else {
NSLog(@"LOGIN IN ACCESS GRANTED");
    NSString *playerFirstName = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"playerfirstname"];

    self.welcomePlayerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Welcome %@", playerFirstName];
    self.loginStatusLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.signButton.hidden = YES;
    self.stepButton.hidden =YES;
    self.loginStatusLabel.text =(@"Access Granted");
    self.loginStatusLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.loginStatusLabel.hidden = NO;

    }
}
```